# Server returns data with strange encoding/compression

Tags: python, base64, gzip, zlib

I'm requesting data from a site which seems like it is returning base64 encoded data. A response looks like this:

```
b'LExRPzI+NlFpUXw2Mj9RW1E1MkUyUWksTFFJUWlgZGdkZ19mYmdnX19fW1FKUWlgXWRbUTUyRTJ7MjM2PURRaUxRSVFpaE5OW0xRSVFpYGRnZGhgYmhjZ19fX1tRSlFpYF1jY19kYk5bTFFJUWlgZGdkaGBmYmVnX19fW1FKUWlgXWNOW0xRSVFpYGRnZGhmaGNlZF9fX1tRSlFpYF1jY19kYk5bTFFJUWlgZGdlX2RjZGFjX19fW1FKUWlgXWNhX2BmW1E1MkUyezIzNj1EUWlMUUlRaVxoTk4uTi4='
```

But, just using `base64.decode` on that byte sequence doesn't give any meaningful data, so there must be some other step in transforming this data.

Here are the headers of this request:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2020 17:48:49 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

It is a GET request to this URL https://www.bestfightodds.com/api?f=ggd&m=20222&p=2

Something that seemed like it could work is

```
data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(r.content))
```

But any kind of decompression always results with `zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`

Comment: I think it should go the other way around. You decompress the bytes, not the base64 decode them. Btw, how did you end up in this situation? If you are using requests, they [handle gzip](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) for you

Comment: Opposite still gives the same error about headers. I am using requests, but response looks exactly like the bytes string above, you can open the link for yourself and see.

Comment: If you are using requests, then you dont have to worry about gzip. Yeah I can see that data looks like base64 and I got the same result as you. Might be encrypted in some other way. I suppose you dont have docs for this?

Comment: No documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously not compressed. After decoding with Base64, the data is highly repetitive.

Comment: Did you end up getting something meaningful from it? Data is supposed to be a time series of betting odds. It doesn't matter to me anymore, but if I decode it I just get rubbish ,LQ?2>6QiQ|62?Q[Q52E2Qi,LQIQi`dgdg_fbgg___[QJQi`]d[Q52E2{236=DQiLQIQihNN[LQIQi`dgdh`bhcg___[QJQi`]cc_dbN[LQIQi`dgdh`fbeg___[QJQi`]cN[LQIQi`dgdhfhced___[QJQi`]cc_dbN[LQIQi`dge_dcdac___[QJQi`]ca_`f[Q52E2{236=DQiLQIQi\hNN.N.